# How important is CSS property order?

Tags: css

Does the order of properties in a CSS declaration have an effect on the rendering of the HTML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently the order does not have any direct impact on the result. 
The subject has been mentioned here: http://css-tricks.com/new-poll-how-order-css-properties/

It does have an impact according to here: http://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/

And here is another trend: http://perishablepress.com/obsessive-css-code-formatting-patterns-and-trends/

Final verdict: Arrange the way you judge best, it will work.

Comment: I was definitely leaning toward listing my properties alphabetically, but after reading the css-trick.com post regarding "real" and "vendor" properties, I think I'll go alphabetic, excepting vendor properties, which I'll place preceding their coorrespondign real properties, treating them as if the vendor prefix was like "The" in a book or band title. Yet another reason to eagerly anticipate all browsers using real properties. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 13):

This is really a trickier question than I first thought. My first reaction was:

Within a CSS *rule* (also called “rule set”), the order of *declarations* (of the form property: value) is immaterial. So `foo { color: red; background: white; }` is equivalent to `foo { background: white; color: red; }`. There is no separate statement about this in specifications (I suppose); it follows from the lack of any statement that would make the order significant.

On second thought, we could also have

```
* { font: 100% Calibri; font-weight: bold; }
```

What happens if you switch the order? In browsers, it does have an effect. I’m not sure how this should be interpreted in terms of CSS specification, but browsers apparently, and naturally, process the declarations sequentially. So the rule makes the text bold, but if you change the order,

```
* { font-weight: bold; font: 100% Calibri; }
```

then things change. The `font` shorthand sets `font-weight` to its initial value `normal`, so the text is not bold.

On third thought, there are many methods and tricks based on the order. So yes, the order of declarations is significant.

The impact of the order of rules is a completely different issue.

Comment: I'm guessing the font example you use above only behaves the way described because the shorthand `font` property is more powerful than the `font-weight` property. At the same time, one could also interpret `font-weight` as being more specific than a shorthand property, so i'm not seeing this any clearer. But in regards to a standard `property:value;` pair, you answered my question.

Comment: There is no special power in `font` or other shorthands. They have simply been defined so that they set all properties in a certain category. Perhaps it would be simpler to consider just `font-weight: bold; font-weight: normal`. The order is significant here. Specificity has nothing to do with this: declarations within one rule share the same specificity.

Comment: So, as long as properties (or short-hand properties) do not **interfere with one another** the order of the properties do not matter? Is this the same for selectors as well?

Answer (score 4):

**Mainly 5 Types Of CSS Property Orde:**

1. Randomly
2. Grouped By
3. Alphabetical
4. By Line Length
5. CSS Properties by Importance

**1. Randomly**

```
.module {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   width: 25%;
   padding: 20px;
   position: relative;
   min-height: 100px;
   z-index: 1;
   border-radius: 20px;
}
```

**2. Grouped By**

```
.module {
   width: 25%;
   min-height: 100px;
   padding: 20px;

   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   border-radius: 20px;

   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

**3. Alphabetical**

```
.module {
   border-radius: 20px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   min-height: 100px;
   padding: 20px;
   position: relative;
   width: 25%;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

**4. By Line Length**

```
.module {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   border-radius: 20px;
   position: relative;
   min-height: 100px;
   padding: 20px;
   z-index: 1;
   width: 25%;
}
```

Here is Refrence URL: https://css-tricks.com/new-poll-how-order-css-properties/

**5. Ordering CSS Properties by Importance**

But Best Way To Ordering CSS Properties by Importance

1. **Layout Properties** (position, float, clear, display)
2. **Box Model Properties** (width, height, margin, padding)
3. **Visual Properties** (color, background, border, box-shadow)
4. **Typography Properties** (font-size, font-family, text-align,
   text-transform)
5. **Misc Properties** (cursor, overflow, z-index)

**Example:**

```
.button {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:1em 4em;
    color:#fff;
    background:#196e76;
    border:0.25em solid #196e76;
    box-shadow:inset 0.25em 0.25em 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 
               0.5em 0.5em 0 #444;
    font-size:3em;
    font-family:Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In normally no need or rule to order of properties in a CSS declaration. I wrote order like my requirements of design and browser response, but in firebug tool it arrange sin **alphabet** order.

The best method of order is

```
 1. box model = width ->height->float
 2. font related = font-size -> text-decoration, font-family
 3. background images = width, height, border, image
```

Then only browser allocate space for each element faster in my experience.

Some persons order like below types:

Random

Alphabetical

Grouped by Type

By properties Length

Answer (score 0):

There are some guidelines. But, at the end of the day it comes down to browser implementation. Try not to rely on a certain order always working, because it won't. Inside a declaration, a statement tends to override a previous statement.