# CSS: same rule, are properties always run in order?

Tags: css, properties

There are tons of questions and answers about *rules precedence*. The question here is about the execution by the browsers of CSS properties within the *same rule*.

Intuitively, I've always considered that properties of a rule are run in order, by the browser.

For instance,

```
  #somediv {
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
  }
```

is rendered as `margin:0 0 10px 0;` (and never `margin:0;`) in the browsers I use (recent Chrome, FF and Safari, basically). Meaning the second property `margin-bottom` overrides the previous `margin` property (that sets all margins to be `0`).

But can I consider this to be *always* true, in **all** browsers (IE, I'm looking at you)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a specific order for CSS properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078431/is-there-a-specific-order-for-css-properties)

Comment: Duplicate? I don't agree as that question specifically insists on browser behavior: is there any browser that wouldn't follow the last-win rule?

Comment: Since you have accepted an answer Ill just add a comment, you were right about your hunch: in some rare cases IE used to be unreliable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior, and part of the [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order) in CSS. You're simply overriding one of the components of the `margin` shorthand with an individual `margin-bottom` value.

Note that it does *not* erase the entire `margin` shorthand declaration completely! Remember that the shorthand you have above can be rewritten as either this:

```
margin: 0 0 0 0;
```

Or this:

```
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: 0;
```

So `margin-bottom: 10px` will simply override the `margin-bottom` above.

Note also that IE6 and older will not give precedence to `!important` declarations within the same rule (but it will honor them in separate rules). But since that's an ancient browser, there's not much of a concern to be honest. This fundamental rule has been well-defined and unchanged [for more than 15 years](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#cascading-order), so browsers have had ample time to implement it correctly and no excuse to fudge it, IE included.

Comment: This is the most correct answer for this specific set of rules - firstly margin-bottom will override margin (shorthand), but also - last rules overwrite previous rules unless your selector is more specific than the previous.

Comment: @Jayx It appears to be so. My concern is more about some (older) browser that wouldn't follow that rule...

Comment: @ring0 no need to be concerned, this has always been the expected behavior for CSS rules.

Comment: I love when these things backfire when shorthands are misunderstood (I am a terrible person). Ask your colleague what will happen if you set `margin-left: 20px;` and then `margin: 5px 10px 15px;` immediately after. Watch them mouth *umm... top, right, bottom... left margin will still be 20px!* Spoiler alert: it will be 10px.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is the correct behaviour according to [w3c specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order):

> If two declarations have the same weight... the latter specified wins

In your example `margin-bottom` would be set as 10px.

The rendering engine does not actually care where the same-specificity property values come from (they could have been set inside of the same rule like in your example, or inside of two rules with identical selectors, or different selectors). If two declarations have the same computed weight, the latter one wins:

```
<style>
  .container span {color:red;}
  .content span {color:blue;}
  div .inner {color:green;}
  p a {color:orange;}    
</style>
<div class="container">
  <p class="content">
    <a href="#" class="button"><span class="inner">Hello world!</span></a>
  </p>
<div>
```

What colour would the text be rendered in? The first three rules have identical specificity, so "Hello world!" would be rendered in green. This gets trickier with shorthand properties though!

Answer (score 2):

Yes if you are declaring two same property but different value than browser will pick up the last declared value for the property

So for example if you are using this

```
div {
   background-color: #ff0000; /*Red*/
   background-color: #00ff00; /*Green*/
}
```

the browser will pick the green because it is declared last

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. the css properties are overwritten in the order they are loaded in all browsers

Answer (score 1):

yeah the one written after always overrides the previous one
if u change the order of the lines tha u have written , ur rerult will be reverted and second line will always lead the first one , so if u have two or more css filed then u should not apply sme styling on the same element in diff css or else u will get some strange css output just depending on the  order of the css file included .